# Find a number $a$ that has the following three properties

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The number 3750 satisfies $\Phi(3750) = 1000$. Find a number $a$ that has the following three properties

$a \equiv 7^{3003}\bmod{3750}$

$1 \leq a \leq 5000 $

$a$ is not divisible by 7

Any help on how to go about this problem, thank you

This is related to Euler's theorem I think

Answer (score 0):

Use [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) to figure out $a \pmod {3750}$
If $a \in [1,1250]$ you can add $3750$ to it and stay in range
As $7$ does not divide into $3750$ evenly, at least one of the two will not be a multiple of $7$

Comment: So is saying that $a^{1000} \equiv 1 (\bmod {3750})$  right by Euler's theorem?

Comment: It is saying $7^{1000}\equiv 1 \pmod {3750}$ by Euler's theorem